# Where in the TensorFlow source code do the Python bindings make the call to the core C++ libraries?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have tried looking around the [source code of the Python bindings](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python) and haven't been able to find where and how exactly the call is made (where Python connects to C++). I have also searched the web quite a bit, without luck, but it may be that I'm not using the right vocabulary for the search. Using `trace` in Python was also not as illuminating as I had hoped. Any nudge in the right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Tensorflow used SWIG to do the bindings, but now they are moving into using [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11).

Inside the code, you can search for PYBIND11_MODULE to find where the new bindings are made. The C++ code compiles to a library file, .so for example on Linux, which can be loaded directly by python.
To learn more about the new and the old method you can check [this RFC](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20190208-pybind11.md).